# Probability mass function over triangular support

Tags: probability

Given $f(x,y) = \frac {xy^2}{13}$ over $(1,1), (1,2), (2,2)$, I am trying to find $f_X(x)$. 
By definition:

$f_X(x) = \sum_{y \in S_Y}f(x,y) = \frac {x}{13} + \frac {4x} {13} = \frac {5x}{13}$.

so that $f_X(1) = 5/13$ and $f_X(2) = 10/13 $. This is obviously wrong. Where am I going off?

Comment: As the support is not rectangular, the summation set may not be identical for each $x$. For $x = 1$ you have $2$ support points $(1, 1), (1, 2)$ and for $x = 2$ you only have $1$ support point $(2, 2)$. Therefore $f_X(1) = f_{X,Y}(1, 1) + f_{X,Y}(1, 2) = 5/13$ while $f_X(2) = f_{X,Y}(2, 2) = 8/13$

Comment: @BGM is there a single formula that can describe $F_X(x)$ that is elementary?

Comment: Sorry I do not get it, do you mean how to obtain the CDF $F_X$ given the pmf we have found?

Comment: the marginal p.m.f of X

Comment: Your formula is fine - you just forget the support of the $(X, Y)$ - $f_{X,Y}(2, 1) = 0$